# Integer part as variable of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I came across the statement
$$\sum_{n>x}^\infty n^{-s}=\int_x^\infty u^{-s}d[u]$$
(where $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}, Re(s)>0, x>0$).
However, I have trouble understanding the integral. How do you handle the differential $d[u]$?

Comment: Hmm ... at first sight that doesn't make sense. Are you sure that it is not $[u]^{-s}du$?

Comment: It is understood either as improper Riemann-Stieltjes integral or as Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. As distribution sense, $d[u]$ is equivalent to the impulse train $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(u-n) \, du$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you; it makes perfect sense!

Comment: @DonAntonio It doesn't give a fully evaluated result. $\frac{x^{1-s}}{s-1}+\{x\}x^{-s}+\int_x^\infty \{u\}du^{-s}$ is what we're left with.